# js2-mode with flycheck and jshint

Tags: flycheck, js2-mode

```
(require 'flycheck)
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook
          (lambda () (flycheck-mode t)))
```

Used this, to setup flycheck for javascript development. However, i noticed config changes in .jshintrc is not considered at all for error highlighting (setting `asi` as true to suppress missing semicolons is one such case.)
Later, i saw that `js2-mode` has inbuilt support for error highlighting. So, what set of rules `js2-mode` and is it as customizable as `flycheck-jshint`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

js2-mode does not use jshint, it will do the syntax check in elisp.

Answer (score 1):

The default checker for `js2-mode` is jshint.

You don't have to use a lambda function to enable `flycheck-mode`.

```
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
(setq flycheck-jshintrc "~/.emacs.d/.jshintrc")
```

or add your own path to the .jshintrc file.

**Later edit:**
To verify your `flycheck` setup for a specific buffer, <kbd>C-c ! v</kbd> or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `flycheck-verify-setup`.