# Does Flycheck interfere with JS-2 Mode?

Tags: flycheck, js2-mode

I realize that `flycheck` is a syntax checker that can be used with nearly every language's major mode.  My question is how (if at all) it can interact with modes such as (specifically) `js2-mode` which offer

> on-the-fly reporting of syntax errors and strict-mode warnings`.

[This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8305/js2-mode-with-flycheck-and-jshint) answers how they are different but I am wondering if it
is better to just pick one mode or can they work together somehow?

I realize this could be opinion based so I am wondering *If someone has an example of them working together* how does it work?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [js2-mode with flycheck and jshint](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8305/js2-mode-with-flycheck-and-jshint)

Comment: @Drew That question explains the difference and what each mode does, I was trying to figure out if they can work together. lunaryorn gives an answer with more substance that what is found in that question.

Answer (score 3):

Flycheck can use many [different Javascript linters](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/languages.html#javascript), including but not limited to eslint, which report far more issues that just syntax errors and strict-mode issues.  For instance eslint can warn you about useless `super()` calls in ES6 constructors, and help you enforce the use of `const` in ES6 code, or warn about using `var` instead of `let` in ES6.

If you can use Flycheck you should do so and disable the built-in checking of JS2 Mode.

Disclosure: I'm a Flycheck maintainer and thus probably biased.

Comment: Can the two not coexist? I've been using them concurrently without issue for a while now.

Comment: They can; JS2 Mode checking is redundant, though. At worst you'll get duplicate warning for the same issue.